# Brocker and Dieck Proposition 6.1 - quaternionic representations

Tags: representation-theory

In Brocker and Dieck's *Representations of Compact Lie Groups*, they define functors between various types of representations. For instance, $r_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}$ takes a quaternionic representation and gives a complex one via regarding the quaternionic vector space as a complex vector space. Explicitly, $r_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}(W,\rho):=\left(V\oplus V,\begin{bmatrix}\rho_1 & -\rho_2 \\ \rho_2 & \rho_1\end{bmatrix}\right)$, where $\rho=\rho_1+j\rho_2$ and $W=V+jV$.

Another functor $e_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}$ takes a complex representation and gives a quaternionic one by extending the scalars. Explicitly, $e_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}(V,\rho):=(\mathbb{H}\otimes_\mathbb{C} V,1\otimes \rho)$, where we view $\mathbb{H}$ as a right $\mathbb{C}$-module. Finally, we have the functor $c$ which takes a complex representation to its conjugate. Explicitly, $c(V,\rho):=(\overline{V},\overline{\rho})$.

In Proposition 6.1, they give the following relationships between these functors: $$e_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}\circ r_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}(W,\rho)\simeq (W,\rho)^{\oplus 2}, \quad 
r_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}\circ e^\mathbb{H}_\mathbb{C}(V,\rho)\simeq (V,\rho)\oplus c(V,\rho), \quad
c\circ r_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}(W,\rho)\simeq r_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}(W,\rho), \quad
e_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}\circ c(V,\rho)\simeq e_\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{H}(V,\rho).$$

I have been able to prove the similar relationships involving real representations, however, the quaternionic representations are proving more difficult, and those kinds of representations are of particular interest to me. Can someone prove one (or more) of these relationships?

Comment: The key point is that these functors can be expressed in terms of tensor products. Restriction corresponds to taking the tensor product with $\mathbb{H}$ over $\mathbb{H}$, but thinking of $\mathbb{H}$ as a $(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H})$-bimodule. Conjugation can also be expressed in this way using a nontrivial $(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C})$-bimdoule structure on $\mathbb{C}$. Then all of these equivalences reduce to checking that certain tensor products of bimodules are isomorphic as bimodules.